# py2neo.database.ClientError: SyntaxError: Invalid input '{': expected "+" or "-" (line 1, column 33 (offset: 32))

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

my python code

```py
        nameu = 'person_%d'%(rel[0])
        namev = 'person_%d'%(rel[1])
        nodeu = graph.nodes.match("Person",name=nameu).first()
        nodev = graph.nodes.match("Person",name=namev).first()
```

```
py2neo.database.ClientError: SyntaxError: Invalid input '{': expected "+" or "-" (line 1, 
column 33 (offset: 32))
"MATCH (_:Person) WHERE _.name = {1} RETURN _"
```

Comment: I tried your script, created my own data and it works for me; can you share your entire code? what is the contents of this set rel?

Comment: I think this is a py2neo version issue. What version are you using?

Comment: @RajendraKadam the version is 2021.2.3

Answer (score 1):

I replace py2neo 4.3.0 with 2021.1.1.
It works.